# Encoding issue with Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am struggling with this issue for almost the whole day today:

I am sending a POST request using Volley on Android with the parameters as string. The string seems fine when I send it in my app, but when it gets to the PHP server somehow the encoding seems different (has characters like %7D etc for curly braces). I am not sure what is going wrong. Due to this json_decode is failing in PHP as it gets a syntax error.

I have tried several things both at the client level and backend level. On client I have tried the following but nothing works.

```
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { 
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            //params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return params;  
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    }
```

On the server side (PHP) I have tried multiple schemes to change it to UTF-8 etc but nothing is working.

Here $data1 has the %7D etc and $data2 becomes null because json_decode fails.

$data1 = file_get_contents('php://input');

$data2 = json_decode($data1);

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a JSON format, try extending JsonRequest instead of Request.

Alternatively:

1. Extend Request, and declare a String field (e.g. params)
   which contains your request parameters.
2. Override getBody:

   @Override
   public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
       return params.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

   }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I have managed to solve it now. Basically I was trying to add 2 entities to this JSON - a String and another object of a class. String was fine but I was simply adding the object directly using "put". I fixed the issue by "put"ting it after doing a Gson.ToJson(). Now its fine :)